# std_logic vector (15 downto 0) value doesn't get assigned

Tags: vector, variable-assignment, vhdl

So, long story short, I'm trying to make a processor of sorts ('of sorts' is put there for a reason, but let's not go into details), and I'm running into one problem which pretty much ruins the whole thing.

Namely, in this piece of code :

```
programmProcess: process (clk,rst) is
    variable counter : natural;
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        counter := 0;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1' and pm_nEn= '1') then
        RAM(counter) <= data; --This is where the issue is
        counter := counter + 1;
        if (counter = 1024) then
            counter := 0;
        end if;
    end if;
    data <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
end process programmProcess;
```

... and this is the testbench process :

```
 stim_proc1: process 
 begin  
    rst <= '1';
    pm_nEn <= '1';
    wait for clk_period;

    rst <= '0' ;

    data <="0000111110111001";
    wait for clk_period;

    data <="0000111010111001";
    wait for clk_period;

    data <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
    pm_nEn <= '0';
    wait for 10*clk_period;
    wait;
end process;
```

... where RAM is an array of 1024 vectors of 16 bits, data is a 16 bit inout vector and pm_nEn is a single bit which basically allows the RAM to be filled with values.

The idea is that RAM(counter) gets values from the data vector, which is manually fed values in the testbench, but this doesn't happen. Namely, all of RAM's values just stay "UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU", despite data having the required values. Even when it's first evaluated and counter is 0, RAM(0) is undefined.

I'm using the ISE suite, and I tried simulating, and then just tracing through all the steps, and the step where RAM(counter) should get assigned a value is shown, the data vector does have the value which is added manually from the testbench, but RAM still doesn't get any values.

So, the question is basically - why does this happen? Why doesn't RAM get its values assigned?

Also, here's the full VHDL and testbench (which was conveniently generated by ISE) in google doc form -

[VHDL](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C1zestA8phlmMsft-FtIUnOUCILg3dG717w0XBkVohs/edit?pli=1)

[Testbench](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16zCqM6nWYGRZXOh0GeZd8wNYcTv5L5ge8JlZzm22g6o/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning "zzzz" to Data within the main process should do no harm (although in the current code fragment, it is redundant).

One thing that *may* lead to problems in synthesis is:

```
 elsif (clk'event and clk = '1' and pm_nEn= '1') then
    ... actions
 end if;
```

To match the pattern a synthesis tool expects for a clocked process, it is better to write

```
 elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
    if pm_nEn= '1' then
       ... actions
    end if;
 end if;
```

though I would expect the two versions to be equivalent in simulation.
There isn't another driver on RAM in another process, is there?

EDIT: apparently there IS a separate driver setting RAM in another process.
Now from a software perspective, you might think that is OK because one process drives when `en = '0'` and the other when `en = '1'`. However you can't make the driver hardware appear and disappear at the flick of a boolean; there are always two drivers on the RAM signal. And the one you aren't explicitly using is holding the value as "UUUU".

The best thing to do is to eliminate one of them. Make one process or the other responsible for writing to RAM. I'll use this process; you may find the design is cleaner and tidier using the other process; that's OK too.

It's easy : just reorganise this process along these lines:

```
 elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
    if pm_nEn= '1' then
       ... actions
    else    -- or elsif external_enable then 
       RAM(external_address) <= external_data;
    end if;
 end if;
```

Incidentally, when you see an expression like `RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3))))))) <= std_logic_vector(signed(OP1) + signed(OP2));`
it's usually a clue that some things have been declared as the wrong types in the first place : for example, OP1 and OP2 should possibly be signed, R should be an array of integers, and so on. If you can't eliminate all the ugliness, you can at least stop it interfering with the main program flow using helper functions (possibly in a package):

```
function gen_reg_addr(IR : Register) return natural is ...

RAM(gen_reg_addr(IR)) <= ...
```

Comment: Well, I'm kinda fuzzy on how drivers work, but maybe this : 

`RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3))))))) <= std_logic_vector(signed(OP1) + signed(OP2));`

... is making problems? 

On the other hand, it's in an `if` clause where pm_nEn is 0, and the other process can only work if pm_nEn is 1, so I didn't really consider the possibility of this being a problem. 

(yes, I'm new to hardware description languages)

Comment: ... but it's in a separate process because it isn't in the code you posted. THAT is the problem.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: No need,that does seem to be the problem. I just need to modify the code a bit but yes - after commenting out that line it does work. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the problem is with the multitude of places where you write to `data`. It wouldn't surprise me if you are having multiple statements write to the same variable, and that should cause the simulator to give it a value of `Z`.

For example, one of your processes looks like this:

```
glavenProcess: process (clk,rst) is
begin
    data <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
    ...
end process;
```

Comment: Well, that was after a suggestion to close the `data` channel to avoid signal collision. And, in any case, removing those assignments seems to actually cause data to be undefined, whereas keeping them there seems to make it work normally, though the assignment to RAM doesn't work.

Comment: @NinoDokoskiot: If I comment out `glavenProcess`, your code works.

Comment: Well color me pleasantly surprised, it does. More over, it does have to do with me being irresponsible with drivers, as Bruan Drummond suggested. Thank you both kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, i found your problem, change RAM to variable instead of Signal, check VHDL manual to see the differences between Signals and variables:

```
        library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use  ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mp is
    port(
        clk, rst, pm_nEn : in std_logic;
        data : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
       adr : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
       rd_nwr : out std_logic
    );
end entity mp;

architecture beh of mp is
    signal PC, IR, OP1, OP2 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    type csignals is array(7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal R: csignals;

    type memory_array is array(1024 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      shared variable RAM: memory_array;
begin                    

    glavenProcess: process (clk,rst) is
    begin
         data <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
        if (rst = '1') then
            PC <= "0000000000000000";
             R(0) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(1) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(2) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(3) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(4) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(5) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(6) <= "0000000000000000";
            R(7) <= "0000000000000001";
        elsif (clk'event and clk = '1' and pm_nEn= '0') then
            IR <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(PC)));
            if (IR(15) = '0') then
                if (IR(14) = '0') then
                        OP1 <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(11 downto 9))));
                else
                        OP1 <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(11 downto 9)))))));
                end if;

                  if (IR(13) = '0') then
                        OP2 <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(8 downto 6))));
                else
                         if (IR(0) = '0') then
                                     adr <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(8 downto 6))));
                                     OP2 <= data;
                                     rd_nwr <= '1' ;
                         else
                                     OP2 <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(8 downto 6)))))));
                         end if;
                end if;

                if (IR(2) = '1') then OP2 <= not OP2 ; end if;
                if (IR(1) = '1') then OP1 <= not OP1 ; end if;

                  if (IR(0) = '0') then
                         if (IR(12) = '0') then
                                 R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3)))) <= std_logic_vector(signed(OP1) + signed(OP2));
                         else
                                 RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3))))))) := std_logic_vector(signed(OP1) + signed(OP2));
                         end if;
                   else
                         if (IR(12) = '0') then
                                 adr <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3))));
                         else
                                 adr <= RAM(to_integer(unsigned(R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(5 downto 3)))))));
                         end if;
                         data <= std_logic_vector(signed(OP1) + signed(OP2));
                         rd_nwr <= '0' ;
                   end if;
                PC <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PC) + 1);
             else
                 if (IR(8 downto 7) = "00") then
                         if (R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(11 downto 9)))) = R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(6 downto 4))))) then
                                 PC <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(14 downto 12))));
                         end if;
                 elsif (IR(8 downto 7) = "01") then
                         if (R(to_integer(signed(IR(11 downto 9)))) > R(to_integer(signed(IR(6 downto 4))))) then
                                 PC <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(14 downto 12))));
                         end if;
                 elsif (IR(8 downto 7) = "10") then
                         if (R(to_integer(signed(IR(11 downto 9)))) < R(to_integer(signed(IR(6 downto 4))))) then
                                 PC <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(14 downto 12))));
                         end if;
                 elsif (IR(8 downto 7) = "11") then
                     if ( not R(to_integer(signed(IR(11 downto 9)))) = R(to_integer(signed(IR(6 downto 4))))) then
                                 PC <= R(to_integer(unsigned(IR(14 downto 12))));
                         end if;
                 end if;
             end if;
         end if;
    end process glavenProcess;

    programmProcess: process (clk,rst) is
        variable counter : natural;
    begin
        if (rst = '1') then
            counter := 0;
        else 
            if (clk'event and clk = '1' and pm_nEn= '1')  then
            RAM(counter) := data;
            counter := counter + 1;                       
            if (counter = 1024) then counter := 0; end if;
        end if;



        end if;

    end process programmProcess;
end architecture beh;
```

Testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    -- Add your library and packages declaration here ...

entity mp_tb is
end mp_tb;

architecture TB_ARCHITECTURE of mp_tb is
    -- Component declaration of the tested unit
    component mp
    port(
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        pm_nEn : in STD_LOGIC;
        data : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        adr : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        rd_nwr : out STD_LOGIC );
    end component;

    -- Stimulus signals - signals mapped to the input and inout ports of tested entity
    signal clk : STD_LOGIC;
    signal rst : STD_LOGIC;
    signal pm_nEn : STD_LOGIC;
    signal data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    -- Observed signals - signals mapped to the output ports of tested entity
    signal adr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal rd_nwr : STD_LOGIC;

    -- Add your code here ...

begin

    -- Unit Under Test port map
    UUT : mp
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            rst => rst,
            pm_nEn => pm_nEn,
            data => data,
            adr => adr,
            rd_nwr => rd_nwr
        );   
        clock:process is
        begin           

           clk<='0';
           wait for 10 ns;
           clk<='1';
           wait for 10 ns;



        end process;
process is
begin
rst <= '1';
    pm_nEn <= '1';



    wait  for 25 ns;
    rst <= '0' ;
    data <="0000111110111001";

    wait  for 45 ns;

    data <="0000111010111001";

    wait  for 55 ns;
    data <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
    pm_nEn <= '0';

    wait;
end process;
end TB_ARCHITECTURE;

configuration TESTBENCH_FOR_mp of mp_tb is
    for TB_ARCHITECTURE
        for UUT : mp
            use entity work.mp(beh);


        end for;
    end for;
end TESTBENCH_FOR_mp;
```

Comment: Tried but it didn't really change anything. `data` still gets its values, though `RAM` doesn't.